# Android Viewpager animation choppy

Tags: android, animation, android-tabhost, android-animation, android-viewpager

I have around 4 (list)views added to my `ViewPager` which acts as a controller to a `TabHost`. Something similar to example found here :

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html

When I fling my finger to go to next view, its not very smooth. I have used the `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` to improve on the animation. Still, it seems choppy.
Can anyone provide any guidelines to have smooth animations ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess here, but is it possible that populating the ListViews takes too much time, thus causing the choppy animations as the ViewPager has to wait for the next View to be instantiated? I've had a similar problem, the cause of which I found out to be SQLite functions being called in a ListAdapter's getView(), causing the delay.

Answer (score -2):

try set the layout parameters at Adapter which extends the pagerAdapter example

```
TextView txt = new TextView(context);
txt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```